# CLSCompliant attribut default value

Tags: .net, visual-studio, cls-compliant

When the attribute `CLSCompliant` is not set in AssemblyInfo, whats its default value (True or False)? If possible, please provide a link to some official source where it was defined.

I looked for for it in the microsoft manuals but i couldnt find the definition.

Comment: It is up to the app that checks for the attribute, typically that would be some kind of IDE.  I don't know of any examples.  But pretty safe to assume that they won't consider an assembly CLSCompliant when it is missing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.clscompliantattribute?view=net-7.0) is fairly clear on this:

> If no CLSCompliantAttribute is applied to a program element, then by default:
>
> - The assembly is not CLS-compliant.
> - The type is CLS-compliant only if its enclosing type or assembly is CLS-compliant.
> - The member of a type is CLS-compliant only if the type is CLS-compliant.
>
> If an assembly is marked as CLS-compliant, any publicly exposed type in the assembly that is not CLS-compliant must be marked with CLSCompliantAttribute using a false argument. Similarly, if a class is marked as CLS-compliant, you must individually mark all members that are not CLS-compliant. All non-compliant members must provide corresponding CLS-compliant alternatives.

So basically, the absence of the attribute is equivalent to `assembly:CLSCompliant(false)`.

Comment: It is indeed. Thanks for you answering my question though!